# Прокси с anglesharp c#

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Не понимаю почему не работает

```
  HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(prxy, false),
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        // var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

        var config = new Configuration().WithRequesters(httpClientHandler).WithDefaultLoader()
       .WithCss()
       .WithJavaScript();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var document = await context.OpenAsync("site");
        foreach (IElement element in document.QuerySelectorAll("div>p"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.TextContent);
        }
```

Comment: что не работает? как не работает, что ожидаете от этого кода?

Comment: не работает обращение к сайту через прокси и я не понимаю почему...

Comment: а как выражается ваше не работает? Если ошибка. то напишите сюда эту ошибку (добавьте в вопросе).

Comment: так проблема в том что и ошибки нет то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий, проблема в чём-то другом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробую угадать:

- на странице нет div > p
- вы не поняли async/await

Comment: правильнее конечно async Task вместо async void - но я дебажить этот код не собирался.